# getting "404 Not Found " or "404 File Not Found "when using Curl and Wget command to get file in Gitlab-ci

Tags: api, curl, gitlab-ci, token, wget

Any help please.
Trying to get the content of .txt file from company repo. but still get this error "404 Not Found " when using Curl command.

- Repo is in gitlab

```
job-test:
  extends: .job_version
  stage: Deploy Image
  needs: ["version"]
  script:
    - 'VERSION="$(curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${PERSO_ACCESS_TOKEN}" "${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/repository/files/xxx%2Dxxx%2Fxxx%2Fxxx%2Dxxx%2Fxxx%2Etxt?/raw?ref=${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}")"'
    - echo voici la version ${VERSION}
  rules:
    - !reference [.rules_script, rules]
```

```
$ VERSION="$(curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${PERSO_ACCESS_TOKEN}" "${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/repository/files/xxx%2Dxxx%2Fxxx%2Fxxx%2Dxxx%2Fxxx%2Etxt?/raw?ref=${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}")"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    32  100    32    0     0    123      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   123
$ echo voici la version ${VERSION}
voici le contenu de V= {"message":"404 File Not Found"}
```

when using `wget` command, the error message change

```
job-test:
  extends: .job_version
  stage: Deploy Image
  needs: ["version"]
  script:
    - 'VERSION="$(wget --verbose --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${PERSO_ACCESS_TOKEN}" "${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/repository/files/xxx%2Dxxx%2Fxxx%2Fxxx%2Dxxx%2Fxxx%2Etxt/raw?ref=${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}")"'
    - echo voici la version ${VERSION}
  rules:
    - !reference [.rules_script, rules]
```

```
--2023-02-08 18:30:14--  https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/34115373/repository/files/xxx%2Dxxx%2Fxxx%2Fxxx%2Dxxx%2Fxxx%2Etxt?/raw?ref=$Develop
Resolving gitlab.com (gitlab.com)... 123.12.123.12, 2606:4700:90:0:f22e:fbec:xxxx:xxx
Connecting to gitlab.com (gitlab.com)|123.12.123.12|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2023-02-08 18:30:14 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

I can not figure out what i did wrong. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Works fine now. The files_path was wrong
Instead of

```
job-test:
  extends: .job_version
  stage: Deploy Image
  needs: ["version"]
  script:
    - 'VERSION="$(curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${PERSO_ACCESS_TOKEN}" "${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/repository/files/xxx%2Dxxx%2Fxxx%2Fxxx%2Dxxx%2Fxxx%2Etxt?/raw?ref=${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}")"'
    - echo voici la version ${VERSION}
  rules:
    - !reference [.rules_script, rules]
```

I use this

```
job-test:
  extends: .job_version
  stage: Deploy Image
  needs: ["version"]
  script:
    - 'VERSION="$(curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${PERSO_ACCESS_TOKEN}" "${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/repository/files/xxx%2Etxt?/raw?ref=${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}")"'
    - echo voici la version ${VERSION}
  rules:
    - !reference [.rules_script, rules]
```

And Booooom